# Converting arraylist to string

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have a multiple line string that is taken as a user input. I broke the string into `ArrayList` by `str.split("\\s ")` and changed a particular word if it occurred, now i want to merge the words in the `ArrayList` with the replaced word in it and form the string again in a multiple line pattern only. I'm not getting how to do this. Please help.

Comment: what you have tried, post here....

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: So you're asking how to concatenate strings?

Comment: `str.split("\\s ")` gives you String[] array, not arrayList. what type do you really have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using only standard Java (assuming your ArrayList is called `words`)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String current : words) 
  sb.append(current).append(" ");
String s = sb.toString().trim();
```

If you have the [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library you can use Joiner:

```
String s = Joiner.on(" ").join(words)
```

Both of these will work even if the type of `words` is `String[]`.

If you want to preserve the line structure, I suggest the following approach: first break the input string into lines by using `.split("\n")`. Then, split each lines to words using `.split("\\s")`. Here's how the code should look like:

```
public String convert(String input, String wordToReplace, String replacement) {
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
  String[] lines = input.split("\n");
  for (String line : lines) {
    boolean isFirst = true;
    for (String current : line.split("\\s")) {
      if (!isFirst)
        result.append(" ");
      isFirst = false;
      if (current.equals(wordToReplace))
        current = replacement;
      result.append(current);
    }
    result.append("\n");
  }

  return result.toString().trim();
}
```

Comment: i guess the problem is concatenating keeping line feeds intact.